# strange behavior with array

Tags: c, arrays, primes

Here's my code, it doesn't works in run-time (in java work fine).

But if I change the line

```
primeNumber[size] = counter;
```

for

```
primeNumber[i] = counter;
```

the program dont crash in run-time. Someone knows why C dont accept that command  **primeNumber[size] = counter;**

thank you!

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){

int primeNumber[90];
primeNumber[0] = 2; //start with 2
int size = 1;
int divisible = 0;
int i = 0;
int counter = 3;


while(counter <= 100){
    divisible = 0;

    for(i = 0; i <= size; i++){
            if(counter%primeNumber[i] == 0){ 
                divisible++;
                break;      
            }
    }

    if(divisible == 0){ 
        primeNumber[size] = counter;
        size = size + 1;
    }       

    counter++;
}

for(i = 0; i <= size; i++){
    printf("\n prime: %d", primeNumber[i]);
}


return 0;
}
```

Comment: **strange** behavior -> **undefined** behavior, very likely ...

Comment: You didn't initialize the array `primeNumber` before using its various indices. In the first iteration of the `while` loop, in the second iteration of the `for` loop, `primeNumber[1]` isn't initialized. This happens for most of the iterations and as iharob has told, invokes Undefined Behavior.

Comment: What will the max value of `size` become? Think about what will happen if it becomes equal to or larger than `90`.

Comment: Also, since you use `i <= size` as condition, the indexing *do* go outside the initialized portion of the array.

Comment: Did you use the debugger? Set Breakpoints? check variables?

Comment: Joachim Pileborg, ok! thanks!

Comment: Fixed your code - off-by-one error twice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your have an error in the `for` loop with the initial value of `size`. Since you use  `i <= size`, `i` reaches `1` during the second iteration and `primeNumber[1]` is not initialized. Use `i < size` instead.

You have the same problem in the last `for` (with the printf), since you increment `size` after changing the value in `primeNumber`, `primeNumber[size]` won't be initialized.

*Note*: With this mistake your code should simply have an aberrant behaviour, not crash.

Answer (score 1):

This was just an off-by-one error. The relevant points are commented in the code below.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){

int primeNumber[90];
primeNumber[0] = 2; //start with 2
int size = 1;
int divisible = 0;
int i = 0;
int counter = 3;


while(counter <= 100){
    divisible = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < size; i++){ // Was error here
            if(counter%primeNumber[i] == 0){ 
                divisible++;
                break;      
            }
    }

    if(divisible == 0){ 
        primeNumber[size] = counter;
        size = size + 1;
    }       

    counter++;
}

for(i = 0; i < size; i++){ // Was error here
    printf("\n prime: %d", primeNumber[i]);
}


return 0;
}
```

Prints:

```
 prime: 2
 prime: 3
 prime: 5
 prime: 7
 prime: 11
 prime: 13
 prime: 17
 prime: 19
 prime: 23
 prime: 29
 prime: 31
 prime: 37
 prime: 41
 prime: 43
 prime: 47
 prime: 53
 prime: 59
 prime: 61
 prime: 67
 prime: 71
 prime: 73
 prime: 79
 prime: 83
 prime: 89
 prime: 97
```

Answer (score 0):

The value of size grows till 98 while the size of array is 90 so increase the size to 100 and it will solve your problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){

int primeNumber[100]; //increased size to 100
primeNumber[0] = 2; //start with 2
int size = 1;
int divisible = 0;
int i = 0;
int counter = 3;


while(counter <= 100){
    divisible = 0;
    //replaced <= with < to avoid floating     point exception
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++){ 
            if(counter % primeNumber[i] == 0){
                divisible++;
                break;
            }
    }

    if(divisible == 0){
        primeNumber[size] = counter;
        size = size + 1;
    }

    counter++;
}

for(i = 0; i <= size; i++){
    printf("\n prime: %d", primeNumber[i]);
}
return 0;
}
```